# Java StringBuilder append methods chain

Tags: java, method-chaining

I have a question. 
For instance:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Teacher,");
String s = sb.append(" Good").append("Morning!").toString();
```

Now in the last line I made a chain of two append methods. I know that each method append method returns an address to the string in memory (I am correct? right?). So in the first `sb.append` it's appending to the address that `sb` points to. And the first `sb.append` is getting executed first in Run-Time but then what happens with the next `.append`? the next `.append` is working with the address that the first append method returned or I am wrong?
This is what I mean:

First append -> `sb.append(" Good");`
Second append `returnedAddr.append("Morning!");`

Is it working in this way?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(java.lang.String) returns a reference thats why.

Answer (score 4):

`sb.append(" Good")` returns a reference to the same `StringBuilder` instance on which the method was called, which allows you to chain another `.append()` call to it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Teacher,");
String s = sb.append(" Good").append("Morning!").toString();
```

is equivalent to

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Teacher,");
sb.append(" Good");
sb.append("Morning!");
String s = sb.toString();
```

Comment: equivalent, but they will differ in speed and how JVM recognizes this code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334233/why-is-the-stringbuilder-chaining-pattern-sb-appendx-appendy-faster-than-reg

Answer (score 3):

`append()` on `StringBuilder` just returns `this` as a convenience.

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append("Good").append(" Morning!").toString();
```

is equivalent to

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("Good");
sb.append(" Morning!");
String s = sb.toString();
```